# Unhandled rejection Error: Script error for "nprogress", needed by: resources/elements/loading-indicator

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I started following the Aurelia tutorial located at [Contact Manager Tutorial](http://aurelia.io/docs/tutorials/creating-a-contact-manager). Everything worked fine till I installed nprogress module and added it to the elements.
I received this error in the browser console.

```
http://localhost:9000/src/nprogress.js net::ERR_ABORTED
vendor-bundle.js:1398 Unhandled rejection Error: Script error for "nprogress", needed by: resources/elements/loading-indicator
```

I am using Esnext and my code is a simple copy paste from the above mentioned tutorial link.

Can someone point me to the right direction on what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error tells us that the module bundler isn't configured correctly. Make sure you have both installed nprogress by running `npm install --save nprogress` from the root of your application (same level as your `package.json` file), and that you have updated your `aurelia.json` file located in the `aurelia_project` folder. You'll need to update it as the instructions explain, and after that, you'll need to re-launch the Aurelia cli using `au run --watch`.

Comment: Thanks Ashley. re-launching the aureila was the missing part. Works perfectly.